# Why are these Element.observe 'ajax:events' firing immediately? - Prototype

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, prototypejs, dom-events

I've got a form_element I want to change the styling of when it is posted.

I changed already working code like this:

```
form_element.observe("ajax:before", function(){ /*do stuff*/ });
```

to this:

```
form_element.observe("ajax:before", changeFormToPostingStyle(form_element));
```

For some reason the second one fires immediately when the page is loaded - and this is regardless of the event. I tried changing the event ajax:complete/success/whatever and it still fires off prematurely. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It triggers at the time of the statement because

```
changeFormToPostingStyle(form_element)
```

is a call to a function and the observe expects that to BE the function or a call to a function that returns a function. Change it to

```
form_element.observe("ajax:before", function() { changeFormToPostingStyle(this) });
```

or

```
form_element.observe("ajax:before", changeFormToPostingStyle);
```

and use `this` in that function

Comment: It is not "Observer" but [`Element.observe`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element#method-observe). However you are right that the function should be passed as an object.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now it looks like my comment is talking about something you didn't do!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if I wanted to clear the observer can I just do: form_element.stopObserving("ajax:before", changeFormToPostingStyle); ?